# REST - Why generated excel file is not actually created when tried as web application?

Tags: java, excel, rest, path, jax-rs

I created simple `REST web app` that would create `Excel file` and put into `current directory.`
But somehow the generated excel is not in the directory. Actually it is not even being created.

The output `"done"` is shown in `GlassFish server log` so the process actually get to the end without any error. The only thing I am suspecting is the file path I'm specifying for "myExcelFileThatWouldNotShowUp".

I gave full path or relative path I can think of but Excel file is not still showing up.
Interestingly, **if I don't run this as web app (i.e. put the code in local main() function and run it, it works)**
Thus I think something to do with GlassFish but can't really figure out :(

- GlassFish v3
- REST / JAX-RS
- Excella framework to generate Excel spreadsheet from template (myTemplate.xls)

**Code snippet**

```
    @Path("horizontalProcess")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getProcessHorizontally() {

        try {
            URL templateFileUrl = this.getClass().getResource("myTemplate.xls");

            //  getPath() outputs... 
            //  /C:/Users/m-takayashiki/Documents/NetBeansProjects/KogaAlpha/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/local/test/jaxrs/myTemplate.xls
            System.out.println(templateFileUrl.getPath());

            String templateFilePath = URLDecoder.decode(templateFileUrl.getPath(), "UTF-8");

            //specify output path which is current dir and should create
            //myExcelFileThatWouldNotShowup.xls but it is not..
            String outputFileDir = "myExcelFileThatWouldNotShowUp";

            //<<template path>>,  <<output path>>,  <<file format>>
            ReportBook outputBook = new ReportBook(templateFilePath, outputFileDir, ExcelExporter.FORMAT_TYPE);

            ReportSheet outputSheet = new ReportSheet("myExcelSheet");
            outputBook.addReportSheet(outputSheet);

            //this is printed out so process actually gets here
            System.out.println("done!!");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


        return null;
    }//end method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why one shouldn't code when tired/overtime worked....

I forgot to add 2 lines of code at the end that actually generate the excel...
cost me couple hours of debugging.. (don't ask how i was debugging :p

```
ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
 reportProcessor.process(outputBook);
```

Btw, generated file are stored in the dir below as default if you don't specify.

```
 //C:\Users\m-takayashiki\.netbeans\6.9\config\GF3\domain1
```